# How to set default date picker arrows in jquery-ui.css?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a problem to set default arrows in choosing months from date picker - can't see arrows, just blank square- [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZHg.png).
How to use default arrow icons?
This is a fragment of my jquery-ui.css file:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span,
    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }
```

In addition to this, when i try to use my own icon (like this):

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span,
    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
        background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/link--v1.png") !important;
        background-position: 0px 0px !important;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }
```

It's working, and I can see some pictures on changing month buttons, But I want to use the default.